# Spring Boot Override Properties Externally

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a `Spring Boot` application that is getting deployed as a `WAR` to a `Tomcat server`. There is already a currently deployed `Spring Boot` application on Tomcat server that has an `application.properties` file on classpath that is overriding the one bundled in the WAR. I need to do the same thing for my application, but I can't use the name `application.properties` as it is already taken, and my application is trying to use the `application.properties` on the classpath from Tomcat, which is intended for the other `Spring Boot` application.

Is there a way I can tell `Spring Boot` to look for a properties file on the classpath called `myapp.properties` or something along those lines?

I tried doing the following, but it doesn't seem to work when being deployed as a WAR.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ParameterManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ParameterManagerApplication.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name:parameter-portal")
            .build()
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Spring Boot looks for the `application.properties` file in these locations.

1. /config subdir of the working directory
2. The working directory
3. config package in the classpath
4. classpath root

So, the following worked for us when we placed `myserver.properties` under any of these locations.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     System.setProperty("spring.config.name","myserver");
     SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
}
```

Otherwise, You can try setting the `spring.config.location` as below.

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:application,myserver",
                        "spring.config.location:classpath:/external/myproperties/")
                .build().run(args);
```

Comment: Does this work with both WAR and JAR, because it doesn't work for me doing WAR deployment but using @PropertrySource did work.

Answer (score 0):

We can also optionally define a custom source where we’re storing these properties, else the default location (classpath:application.properties) is looked up. So we now add the above annotations to the existing properties class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:configprops.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dev")
public class ConfigProperties {
    // previous code
}
```

Now any properties defined in the property file that has the prefix **dev** and the same name as one of the properties are automatically assigned to this object.

```
#Simple properties
dev.host=mailer@mail.com
dev.port=9000
```

Check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)